# How do I percent-escape a Base64 string in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, escaping, uri

In a Ruby program I have a password that is a Base64 string and so can contain forward slashes. I use that password and the username to perform HTTP requests

```
username = "User"
password = "/Base/64/With/Slashes"
requestUrl = "http://#{username}:#{password}@company.com"
response = RestClient.get(requestUrl)
```

so if `password` happens to contain forward-slashes those will be interpreted as port of the URI and I'll have an error message saying I have an invalid URI. Clearly each forward slash inside `password` must be replaced with `%2F`.

I tried to use `URI.escape()`, but it doesn't affect forward slashes.

How do I percent-escape Base64 string so that the result can be used for HTTP requests authentication?

Comment: How about `CGI.escape(password)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@injekt has the right answer in a comment, but here's a slightly elaborated version as an answer:

[CGI.escape()](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/cgi/rdoc/CGI.html#method-c-escape) is an appropriate tool for that task.  Its documentation:

> URL-encode a string.